# Ambiguous/useless tag "masters"

Tags: discussion, tags

[masters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masters) seems to refer to getting a Master's degree in college, Master is in Master/Slave architecture or Masters as in people who have mastered a craft. I'll note there's also a [degree](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/degree) tag.

I'm not really sure if any of these are relevant here aside from the architecture pattern but they really shouldn't have the same tag.

Comment: I just retagged two of `masters` that looked blatantly irrelevant

Comment: There are 8 masters questions, why not just edit them and remove the tag? Won't it die on its own if it's not used?

Comment: Found you an even worse: [undergraduate-masters](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/undergraduate-masters) - removing it from the questions now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ben, you are imagining things. What [masters] tag? ;P

Keep an eye out for it, if it comes back it might be worth blacklisting.